# How to access a currently active CLR instead of creating a new one

Tags: c#, c++, windows, com, clr

## The problem

My goal is to be able to inject and eject a C# DLL into an arbitrary process. The way to go seems to be to inject a C++ DLL that loads and starts the CLR and starts execution of the C# code with ICLRRuntimeHost::ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain. After the C# code is processed, control is passed back to the C++ DLL, some sort of clean up is performed and the C++ code is ejected. This part works fine. The problem arises when trying inject the C++ DLL again into the same process after the injection/ejection succeeded. According to [ICLRRuntimeHost::Stop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/hosting/iclrruntimehost-stop-method) you can't

> [...] release resources to the host, unload application domains, or destroy threads. You must terminate the process to release these resources.

If I am not mistaken, this means that the CLR can't be unloaded once loaded into a process. Naturally, my next attempt was to "reuse" the previously loaded CLR. If the CLR can't be unloaded at the end of the first injection/ejection cycle it must still be present when injecting the second time. My question is how to do that. **How do you access a currently active CLR instead of creating a new one?**

## What I've got

Upon receiving `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` the C++ DLL's DllMain function creates a thread that executes the `Main` function:

```
CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Main, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

`Main` performes some COM and CLR unrelated tasks before calling `CallCSharp` and `FreeLibraryAndExitThread`:

```
void Main()
{
    ...
    CallCSharp(cSharpDLLpath);
    FreeLibraryAndExitThread(hmodule, 0);
}
```

`CallCSharp` is where the magic happens:

```
void CallCSharp(std::wstring& cSharpDLLpath)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    ICLRMetaHost* pMetaHost = NULL;
    ICLRRuntimeInfo* pRuntimeInfo = NULL;
    ICLRRuntimeHost* pClrRuntimeHost = NULL;
    DWORD returnValue{}, flags{};
    BOOL isLoaded{}, isLoadable{}, isStarted{};

    wchar_t newestCLRversion[] = L"v4.0.30319";

    // Initialize COM
    hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

    // Bind to the CLR runtime..
    hr = CLRCreateInstance(CLSID_CLRMetaHost, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pMetaHost));

    // Get the ICLRRuntimeInfo interface for the given CLR version
    hr = pMetaHost->GetRuntime(newestCLRversion, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pRuntimeInfo));

    // Determine whether this version of the CLR has already been loaded into this process
    hr = pRuntimeInfo->IsLoaded(GetCurrentProcess(), &isLoaded);

    // Determine whether the CLR is loadable in this process
    hr = pRuntimeInfo->IsLoadable(&isLoadable);

    // Determine whether the CLR has already been started
    hr = pRuntimeInfo->IsStarted(&isStarted, &flags);

    // Load the CLR
    hr = pRuntimeInfo->GetInterface(CLSID_CLRRuntimeHost, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pClrRuntimeHost));

    // Push the big START button if the CLR hasn't already been started
    if (isStarted == TRUE)
        hr = pClrRuntimeHost->Start();

    // Okay, the CLR is up and running in this (previously native) process.
    // Now call a method on our managed C# class library.
    hr = pClrRuntimeHost->ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain(cSharpDLLpath.c_str(), L"Main.MainClass", L"MainMethod", L"", &returnValue);

    // Stop the CLR runtime
    hr = pClrRuntimeHost->Stop();

done:
    // Don't forget to clean up.
    SafeRelease(pClrRuntimeHost);
    SafeRelease(pRuntimeInfo);
    SafeRelease(pMetaHost);

    // Uninitialize COM
    CoUninitialize();

    return;
}
```

(error handling omitted for brevity)

This works fine for the first injection/ejection cycle but during the second cycle `ICLRRuntimeHost::ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain()` fails with `HOST_E_CLRNOTAVAILABLE (0x80131023)`.

## What I've tried

- Calling `ICLRRuntimeHost::Start()` during the second injection/ejection even though `ICLRRuntimeInfo::IsStarted()` results in `TRUE` (in the code above this is prevented by `if (isStarted == TRUE)`) leads to `HOST_E_CLRNOTAVAILABLE (0x80131023)` in `ICLRRuntimeHost::ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain()`.
- Omitting `ICLRRuntimeHost::Stop()` (btw. what does this method even do if it doesn't unload the CLR?) leads to `E_HANDLE (0x80070006)` in `ICLRRuntimeHost::ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain()`.
- Both omitting `ICLRRuntimeHost::Stop()` and calling `ICLRRuntimeHost::Start()` during the second injection/ejection leads to `E_HANDLE (0x80070006)` in `ICLRRuntimeHost::ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain()`.

According to Microsoft the method that actually loads the CLR into a process is [ICLRRuntimeInfo::GetInterface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/hosting/iclrruntimeinfo-getinterface-method). However, by providing a pointer to the `ICLRRuntimeHost` interface it fulfills a crucial part, it can't just be omitted. One solution would be a function that provides a pointer to the `ICLRRuntimeHost` interface of an already active CLR. Unfortunatelly I couldn't find such a function.

Comment: Is your entry method throwing any exceptions? https://stackoverflow.com/q/9127284/1462295

Comment: @BurnsBA I am assuming 'entry method' means my C# code? No, for now my C# code is just an empty method. And because everything works during the first injection my C# code can't be the problem.